# How to fix `ReferenceError: procglobal is not defined` when importing custom function from another file?

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, webpack, clasp

I'm working on a simple template project for creating new Web Apps in Google Apps Script using TypeScript, CLASP, & Webpack + gas-webpack-plugin.

Everything works fine *until* I try to reference a function I wrote in another file, in this case, `updateTable` in my form handler; Webpack transpiles without issue, but then GAS complains that `procglobal` isn't defined.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with my Webpack config, but I haven't the slightest clue where to start looking.

form/code.ts

```
import { updateTable } from "../table/code";

export function processForm(formObject: FormSubmission) {
  const formData: string[] = formObject[""];
  updateTable({
    rowNumber: formData[0],
    firstName: formData[1],
    lastName: formData[2],
    handle: formData[3],
  });
}
```

table/code.ts

```
export function updateTable(row: TableRow) {
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const table = JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty("tableData"));
  const newTable = { ...table, ...row };
  scriptProperties.setProperty("tableData", JSON.stringify(newTable));
}
```

code.ts

```
import "./app/home/do-get";
import "./app/form/code";
import "./app/modal/code";
import "./app/table/code";
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const GasPlugin = require("gas-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./src/code.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /(\.ts)$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"],
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "build/Code.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new GasPlugin({
      autoGlobalExportsFiles: ["**/*.ts"],
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "**/*.html", to: "build", context: "src" },
        { from: "appsscript.json", to: "build" },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

webpack generated code

```js
var global = this;
function processForm() {}
function getForm() {}
function doGet() {}
function appTitle() {}
function updateTable() {}
function getTable() {}
function getTableData() {}
(() => {
  var e = {
      963: (e, t, r) => {
        "use strict";
        Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", { value: !0 }),
          (t.processForm = t.getForm = void 0),
          r(661),
          (t.getForm = function () {
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(
              "app/form/index"
            ).getContent();
          }),
          (t.processForm = procglobal.processForm = t.processForm), // <-- error on procglobal, only appears when processForm includes an imported function
          (global.getForm = t.getForm),
          essForm;
      },
      237: (e, t) => {
        "use strict";
        Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", { value: !0 }),
          (t.doGet = t.appTitle = void 0),
          (t.appTitle = "Google Apps Script template"),
          (t.doGet = function () {
            return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index")
              .evaluate()
              .setTitle(t.appTitle);
          }),
          (global.doGet = t.doGet),
          (global.appTitle = t.appTitle);
      },
      199: () => {},
      661: function (e, t) {
        "use strict";
        var r =
          (this && this.__assign) ||
          function () {
            return (
              (r =
                Object.assign ||
                function (e) {
                  for (var t, r = 1, a = arguments.length; r < a; r++)
                    for (var o in (t = arguments[r]))
                      Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, o) &&
                        (e[o] = t[o]);
                  return e;
                }),
              r.apply(this, arguments)
            );
          };
        function a() {
          var e = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(),
            t = JSON.parse(e.getProperty("tableData"));
          return console.log(t), t;
        }
        Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", { value: !0 }),
          (t.updateTable = t.getTableData = t.getTable = void 0),
          (t.getTable = function () {
            var e = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("app/table/index");
            return (e.tableData = a()), e.evaluate().getContent();
          }),
          (t.getTableData = a),
          (t.updateTable = function (e) {
            var t = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(),
              a = JSON.parse(t.getProperty("tableData")),
              o = r(r({}, a), e);
            t.setProperty("tableData", JSON.stringify(o));
          }),
          (global.updateTable = t.updateTable),
          (global.getTable = t.getTable),
          (global.getTableData = t.getTableData);
      },
    },
    t = {};
  function r(a) {
    var o = t[a];
    if (void 0 !== o) return o.exports;
    var l = (t[a] = { exports: {} });
    return e[a].call(l.exports, l, l.exports, r), l.exports;
  }
  (() => {
    "use strict";
    r(237), r(963), r(199), r(661);
  })();
})();
```

---

If I remove the `updateTable` function from `form/code.ts`, the `procglobal` disappears...

form/code.ts:

```
import { updateTable } from "../table/code";

export function getForm() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("app/form/index").getContent();
}

export function processForm(formObject: FormSubmission) {
  const formData: string[] = formObject[""];
  console.log({
    rowNumber: formData[0],
    firstName: formData[1],
    lastName: formData[2],
    handle: formData[3],
  });
}
```

new webpack generated code:

```js
var global = this;
function processForm() {}
function getForm() {}
function doGet() {}
function appTitle() {}
function updateTable() {}
function getTable() {}
function getTableData() {}
(() => {
  var e = {
      963: (e, t) => {
        "use strict";
        Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", { value: !0 }),
          (t.processForm = t.getForm = void 0),
          (t.getForm = function () {
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(
              "app/form/index"
            ).getContent();
          }),
          (t.processForm = function (e) { // <-- no procglobal
            var t = e[""];
            console.log({
              rowNumber: t[0],
              firstName: t[1],
              lastName: t[2],
              handle: t[3],
            });
          }),
          (global.processForm = t.processForm),
          (global.getForm = t.getForm);
      },
      237: (e, t) => {
        "use strict";
        Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", { value: !0 }),
          (t.doGet = t.appTitle = void 0),
          (t.appTitle = "Google Apps Script template"),
          (t.doGet = function () {
            return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index")
              .evaluate()
              .setTitle(t.appTitle);
          }),
          (global.doGet = t.doGet),
          (global.appTitle = t.appTitle);
      },
      199: () => {},
      661: function (e, t) {
        "use strict";
        var r =
          (this && this.__assign) ||
          function () {
            return (
              (r =
                Object.assign ||
                function (e) {
                  for (var t, r = 1, a = arguments.length; r < a; r++)
                    for (var o in (t = arguments[r]))
                      Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, o) &&
                        (e[o] = t[o]);
                  return e;
                }),
              r.apply(this, arguments)
            );
          };
        function a() {
          var e = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(),
            t = JSON.parse(e.getProperty("tableData"));
          return console.log(t), t;
        }
        Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", { value: !0 }),
          (t.updateTable = t.getTableData = t.getTable = void 0),
          (t.getTable = function () {
            var e = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("app/table/index");
            return (e.tableData = a()), e.evaluate().getContent();
          }),
          (t.getTableData = a),
          (t.updateTable = function (e) {
            var t = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(),
              a = JSON.parse(t.getProperty("tableData")),
              o = r(r({}, a), e);
            t.setProperty("tableData", JSON.stringify(o));
          }),
          (global.updateTable = t.updateTable),
          (global.getTable = t.getTable),
          (global.getTableData = t.getTableData);
      },
    },
    t = {};
  function r(a) {
    var o = t[a];
    if (void 0 !== o) return o.exports;
    var l = (t[a] = { exports: {} });
    return e[a].call(l.exports, l, l.exports, r), l.exports;
  }
  (() => {
    "use strict";
    r(237), r(963), r(199), r(661);
  })();
})();
```

Comment: Good question, where is it?  I don't see it defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: @TheWizEd - as far as I can tell, I'm *not* adding or defining it anywhere in my code; it's being autogenerated by webpack and/or gas-webpack-plugin. I just can't tell how, but it's def *not* there when `processForm` function code is isolated.

Comment: Then you need to find where its defined.

Comment: Is it by any chance global and not procglobal?

Comment: @TheWizEd - updated the question with code auto-generated when `updateTable` is *not* used in `form/code.ts`... `procglobal` simply disappears. Any thoughts?